# issue in combining python list and numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have two python lists and a numpy array. The numpy array looks like this:

```
[array([93495052.969556, 98555123.061462])]
[array([1000976814.605984, 998276347.359732])]
[array([6868127850.435482, 6903911250.620625])]
[array([775127467.947004, 802369832.938230])]
```

this `numpy array` is formed from following code:

```
array1 = []
company = []
state = []

def process_chunk(chuk):

    training_set_feature_list = []
    training_set_label_list = []
    test_set_feature_list = []
    test_set_label_list = []
    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

    array2 = []


    # to divide into training & test, I am putting line 10th and 11th in test set
    count = 0
    for line in chuk:
        # Converting strings to numpy arrays
        if count == 9:   
            test_set_feature_list.append(np.array(line[3:4],dtype = np.float))
            test_set_label_list.append(np.array(line[2],dtype = np.float))
            company.append(line[0])
            state.append(line[1])
        elif count == 10:
            test_set_feature_list.append(np.array(line[3:4],dtype = np.float))
            test_set_label_list.append(np.array(line[2],dtype = np.float))

        else:    
            training_set_feature_list.append(np.array(line[3:4],dtype = np.float))
            training_set_label_list.append(np.array(line[2],dtype = np.float))
        count += 1
    # Create linear regression object
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    # Train the model using the training sets
    regr.fit(training_set_feature_list, training_set_label_list)

    #print test_set_feature_list

    array2.append(np.array(regr.predict(test_set_feature_list),dtype = np.float))
    np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':'{:f}'.format})
    for items in array2:
        array1.append(items)
```

`array1` is the numpy array that I want to join with two python lists

First python list is `company` which looks like this:

`['OT', 'OT', 'OT', 'OT',....]`

Second python list is state:

`['Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Alabama', ...]`

Now what I am trying to do is form one list which has following structure:

```
('OT', 'Alabama', 729, 733)
('OT', 'Alabama', 124, 122)
('OT', 'Arizona', 122, 124)
```

I wrote this line of code - `final_list = zip(company,state,array1)` but this produces this output (with added `array` and `[]` around array elements):

```
('OT', 'Alabama', array([729, 733]))
('OT', 'Alabama', array([124, 122]))
```

How do I join these lists and array so as to form one list which does not have above issue?

Comment: What does array1 look like? Can you do `print(array1)` and update its result?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Its shown in my post above

Comment: @AnandSKumar I have provided my exact code which forms array1 and array2. The function is run multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `array1` looks something like -

```
array1 = np.array([np.array([729, 733]), np.array([124, 122]) ...])
```

Though given your code (and usage of `array1.append()` , it looks like `array1` is a list) . You can first convert the `array1` list into `numpy.array` as -

```
narray1 = np.array(array1)           #This step not necessary , if array1 is already numpy array , in that case use `array1` instead of `narray1` .
```

Then if there are only two values per elements, you can do -

```
final_list = zip(company,state,narray1[:,0], narray1[:,1])
```

---

Demo -

```
In [59]: array1 = [np.array([729, 733]), np.array([124, 122])]

In [60]: company = ['OT', 'OT']

In [61]: state = ['Alabama', 'Alabama']

In [62]: narray1 = np.array(array1)

In [63]: final_list = zip(company,state,narray1[:,0], narray1[:,1])

In [65]: final_list
Out[65]: [('OT', 'Alabama', 729, 733), ('OT', 'Alabama', 124, 122)]
```

Comment: I am getting some weird output structure. It might be because of the way my numpy array is formed. I have updated my post above to include code which form the numpy array

Comment: What is the output you are getting after using `*` ?

Comment: Instead of array1 , try using `array2` , What is the result of `regr.predict(test_set_feature_list)` like ?

Comment: `array2` is temporary array inside my code and `array1` is the global array. I am not using `array2` because with each iteration of the code it gets refreshed. So before it gets refreshed I add the contents of array2 to global array1

Comment: Then you would need to show an exact print of `array1` , the array you show does not look like a valid array (pointing to the array in the question) .

Comment: @user2966197 try the latest, assuming there are only two values for each inner element.

Comment: How can write this list into a csv file in ipython?

Comment: The elements of `array1`  are not `np.array()` of two elements ?

Comment: the error was temporary. A small mistake in my part for which I apologize.How can write this list into a csv file in ipython?

Comment: you can use `csv` module . open file, use `csv.writer()` , and then pass in the zipped list to `writer.writerows()` .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to create a structured array, or its list equivalent (a list of tuples)

For convenience, lets just creat a list of tuples with your data.  I won't get into the details of how this can be created from the other pieces (for now):

```
In [19]: data = [('OT', 'Alabama', 729, 733),
('OT', 'Alabama', 124, 122),
('OT', 'Arizona', 122, 124)]
```

Define a compound `dtype` (one of several possible formats):

```
In [23]: dt = np.dtype('S2,S10,i,i')
```

and the structured array:

```
In [24]: A=np.array(data,dtype=dt)

In [25]: A
Out[25]: 
array([('OT', 'Alabama', 729, 733), ('OT', 'Alabama', 124, 122),
       ('OT', 'Arizona', 122, 124)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S2'), ('f1', 'S10'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
```

which can be accessed by field name:

```
In [26]: A['f1']
Out[26]: 
array(['Alabama', 'Alabama', 'Arizona'], 
      dtype='|S10')

In [27]: A['f2']
Out[27]: array([729, 124, 122])
```

convert back to a list of tuples:

```
In [28]: A.tolist()
Out[28]: 
[('OT', 'Alabama', 729, 733),
 ('OT', 'Alabama', 124, 122),
 ('OT', 'Arizona', 122, 124)]
```

You can also create an empty (or zero) array of the right size and dtype, and fill it, row by row, or field by field

```
A1 = np.zeros((3,),dtype=dt)
A1['f0']=['OT','OT','OT']
A1['f2']=np.array([729,124,122])
etc
```

if the numbers are in a (3,2) integer array, you could use:

```
A1['f2']=x[:,0]
A1['f3']=x[:,1]
```